# Create a class to store classes that use different interfaces

Tags: c#, class

I am working on a project in C# which needs to store information about a user. This information is retrieved from their respective libraries which have their own implementations and interfaces. Currently users can either connect from Twitch or Discord, so they will be represented as either TwitchUser or DiscordUser objects. However, I would like to write a class User that will contain one of the 2 classes which should make it easier for me to refer to them in code.

Here is an example of how TwitchUser and DiscordUser look like:

```
    public class TwitchUser : IChatUser
    {
        public TwitchUser();

        public string Id { get; }
        public string UserName { get; }
        public string DisplayName { get; }
        public string Color { get; }
//and so on...
    }
```

```
    public class DiscordUser : SnowflakeObject, IEquatable<DiscordUser>
    {
        public virtual string Email { get; internal set; }
        public virtual string Username { get; internal set; }
        public bool Equals(DiscordUser e);
//and so on...
    }
```

I thought I could create a class which accepts generic types but with my implementation I would have to pass BOTH classes which means one of them would be null. This doesn't feel right to me.

```
    public class User<T,D>
    {
        public TwitchUser VarA { get; set; }
        public DiscordUser VarB { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the correct way of combining 2 classes that have different implementations and don't have interfaces in common between?
I would then also write code inside my **User** class to return user IDs etc.

**Update**
For example, when I request a user ID I would perform a check inside **User** whether I stored a TwitchUser or DiscordUser, and based on the outcome I would return an attribute which represents the user's ID on that platform.

**Update 2**
A user may only be represented by one of the two classes. For example, if they used Discord as their platform to login then they will only have a DiscordUser object associated with them. Same applies to Twitch platform and it using TwitchUser object. The reason they are different is because these implementation were written by different people using 2 different libraries, which is why they don't use the same interfaces, or inherit from one common class. So what I am trying to do is retroactively add some sort of an inheritance here. This way, when I want to refer to the user in my code, I don't need to write 2 overloads for a function (where one uses **TwitchUser** and the other uses **DiscordUser**). I just want to be able to refer to **User** and let that class decide for me.

Comment: This all depends on what exactly you want to do, and you've spent about half a sentence explaining that: "return user IDs etc". What does that mean? What are you going to do with the data? What if on one end the email address is the identifier, and on the other end a username is unique? Or what if one service has its own identifier, like a GUID? As for your implementation, you don't even use the generic type parameters. T and D have no relation whatsoever to TwitchUser and DiscordUser.

Comment: You _could_ consider writing your own interface having properties like `string UserId { get; }`, and let those classes you show implement that interface: `public string UserId { get { return Username; }}`, for example.

Comment: I have added a short update explaining the User ID use case. Of course, if I want to return other attributes I would again perform the check in a similar fashion and return the appropriate attribute from either of the classes. Obviously, if neither of the classes contain common attributes (for example, TwitchUser has IsSubscriber and DiscordUser doesn't) then I won't bother with implementating a function to return that attribute.

Comment: It's not clear to me when and why you would have an instance of either or both of these, and which properties you're interested in and when and why. What if a user has both a Twitch _and_ a Discord account? You really need to provide more context.

Comment: I have added another update which should hopefully explain my situation better.

Comment: Why can you not just create a class that has the properties you want to use, and then populate an instance of it when the user logs in?

Comment: _"when I want to refer to the user in my code [...] I just want to be able to refer to User"_ - and then _what_? What do you want to do? Again, look at my interface suggestion.

Comment: Problem is, those 2 clases I mentioned cannot be modified as they are part of their respective libraries. By the time they reach my code they would have already been instantiated. I could go and edit Discord and Twitch libraries to implement my interface but that's not a good idea. Instead, I want to be able to combine these 2 classes up into 1 class which is agnostic to the platform that the end user is using. In the future, I might add another service to my code (which would also use its own library/implementation), but I would still want to refer to just one class - the **User** class.

Comment: Regarding what it is that I want to do with my **User** class - I want to be able to access all the necessary attributes stored in DiscordUser and TwitchUser objects. For example, calling **User.Id** should return user ID from either TwitchUser **or** DiscordUser, depending on which class was used to create the **User** object in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> those 2 clases I mentioned cannot be modified [...] I want to be able to access all the necessary attributes stored in DiscordUser and TwitchUser

That sounds like a good fit for the adapter pattern. Define an interface as common denominator:

```
public interface IUser
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Username { get; }
}
```

Note that this interface can only contain properties that *both* objects share, or you're going to need null checks all over the place.

Then create an adapter for each type you want to wrap:

```
public class TwitchUserAdapter : IUser
{
    private readonly TwitchUser _user;
    
    public TwitchUserAdapter(TwitchUser user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
    
    public string Id => _user.Id;
    public string Username => _user.UserName;
}

public class DiscordUserAdapter : IUser
{
    private readonly DiscordUser _user;
    
    public TwitchUserAdapter(DiscordUser user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
    
    public string Id => _user.Id;
    public string Username => _user.Username;
}
```

Now you can treat both the same:

```
var users = new List<IUser>();

users.Add(new TwitchUserAdapter(new TwitchUser { Id = "Tfoo", UserName = "Tbar" }));
users.Add(new DiscordUserAdapter(new DiscordUser { Id = "Dfoo", Username = "Dbar" }));

foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {user.Id}, Name: {user.Username}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"What is the correct way of combining 2 classes that have different implementations and don't have interfaces in common between?"*

One way to accomplish this might be to create a class that contains all the properties you care about, and then create static methods that return an instance of the class based on the properties of a `TwitchUser` or a `DiscordUser`:

```
public class User
{
    // Add just the properties you care about
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public string Color { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }

    // Make the default constructor private so instances of this
    // class can only be created from one of our static methods
    private User() { }

    public static User FromTwitch(TwitchUser twitchUser)
    {
        return new User
        {
            Id = twitchUser.Id,
            Color = twitchUser.Color,
            DisplayName = twitchUser.DisplayName,
            UserName = twitchUser.UserName
        };
    }

    public static User FromDiscord(DiscordUser discordUser)
    {
        return new User
        {
            Email = discordUser.Email,
            UserName = discordUser.Username
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just introduce an interface `IUser` that has these properties, and let those two classes implement that interface?

Comment: That would work also, if he has control over those classes. I don't fully understand his scenario